# In Svelte how can I unshift to an array without triggering onMount of child components

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have an array of components that I'm dynamically loading using svelte:component inside of an each block. Each component are performs a task when it start in the onMount function. The user can select a component from a list to have it added to the array.

If I push to the array (add to the end) and then reassign the new component is added to the end and the previous components do not re-initialize. The newly added test runs as desired. HOWEVER, if I unshift and then reassign ALL of the the components onMount functions run again. Is there a way to avoid this behavior or a better way to persist the state of the individual components after new items are added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a key? See [`#each` documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each).

```html
<!-- Statement in parentheses identifies item -->
{#each items as item (item)}
```